# How do you remove an object from an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I was wondering how do you remove objects from an `NSMutableArray`, cause right now I use `[astroids removeFromSuperview];` but it just gets rid of the image on screen but the instance itself is still present even when removed.

Comment: As a general note: there is a lot of documentation from Apple available both online and bundled with the developer tools (Help > Documentation), which is a very good way to answer basic questions about how you use a given class.

Answer (score 14):

`-removeFromSuperview` is a method of `UIView`, not `NSMutableArray`.  It seems that the `UIView` instance you're calling that on is also kept in an `MSMutableArray`.  You will need to use one of the `NSMutableArray` methods for removing objects on the array itself.

It is necessary to remove it in the array separately because it also owns the object in question, and has retained it independently of its use elsewhere.

**NSMutableArray Methods for Removing Objects:**

```
– removeAllObjects  
– removeLastObject  
– removeObject:  
– removeObject:inRange:  
– removeObjectAtIndex:  
– removeObjectsAtIndexes:  
– removeObjectIdenticalTo:  
– removeObjectIdenticalTo:inRange:  
– removeObjectsFromIndices:numIndices:  
– removeObjectsInArray:  
– removeObjectsInRange:
```

See http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablearray_Class/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` contains a `removeObjectAtIndex` message.
[NSMutableArray documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablearray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Also `removeObject:`, if all you have is the object and you don't want to look for its first index yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are removing a view from its superview, then the *removeFromSuperview* does not send a *release* message to your view, that would cause it to be immediately freed (if no other objects did retain it).

Instead it sends an *autorelease* message. This causes the view to actually get removed from memory at the end of the run loop, not immediately after your *removeFromSuperview* message.